# how to translate a Dictionary list to a List<IList<object>> for Google Spreadsheet API

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I am having some trouble finding correct examples for inserting data into a Google Spreadsheet using the Google Spreadsheet API v4.

The example in Google's docs is the following :

```
Data.ValueRange requestBody = new Data.ValueRange();
requestBody.Values = new List<IList<object>> {  };

SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest sheetRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(requestBody, spreadsheetId, rangeClasses);
sheetRequest.ValueInputOption = valueInputOption;
sheetRequest.InsertDataOption = insertDataOption;
```

Inserting strings in the `requestBody.Values` list works fine. But I would like to translate a `Dictionary<int,int>` into something compatible with `Data.ValueRange`.

Any idea ?

Comment: What does your dictionary look like? What type is it? How exactly did you expect it to be inserted?

Comment: The question is a little under-specified (or maybe it's my lack of knowledge about Goolge API). Which values do you need to put into the request? The _values_ of the dictionary or also the _keys_? Should those values be in one `IList` of the `List<IList<object>>` or each value in a single `IList`?

Comment: @MattBurland it's a dictionnary of integer keys and integer values, e.g. :
[1000,2040]
[2000,19]
[3000,22]

I want to simply put it as two columns, one for keys, one for values. As if I wanted to print the dictionary from a foreach

`foreach(KeyValuePair kvp in dictionary)
{
Console.Writeline(kvp.key+","+kvp.Value);
}
`

Comment: @RenéVogt I'm actually a bit lost myself on where the values should be.

But regarding the content, I want the values as well as the keys to be inserted in the sheets as two columns : one for keys, one for values

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is how to turn a `Dictionary<T,S>` into a `List<List<object>>`, then you can do something like this:

```
var list = dic.Select(d => new object[] { d.Key, d.Value });
```

That you turn a dictionary like this:

```
{
    "foo":1,
    "bar":2
}
```

Into an array like this:

```
[
    [ "foo", 1 ],
    [ "bar", 2 ]
]
```

An important caveat here though is that *dictionaries are unordered*, so there is no guarantee that when you iterate it with `Select`, you'll get the keys in the same order as you put them in. So the keys could be in any random order.

If you need them to be *in order*, you would need to create an array with the keys in the order you need and then use that to build your list. For example:

```
var orderedList = new [] { "foo", "bar" }.Select(k => new object[] { k, dic[k] });
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ these are the keys in the order I want!
```

Comment: Thanks matt ! Unfortunately I get the following error : `cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object[]>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Collections.Generic.IList<object>>'`

My Dictionary is <int,int> and order does not really matter :)

Comment: @AlexadreG: my bad, just stick a `ToList()` on the end. Come to think of it, you might want `new List<object>` instead of `new object[]`

Comment: Almost ! I'm getting the following error now : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<object>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Collections.Generic.IList<object>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)